# Android multi-core development

Tags: android, multithreading, android-3.0-honeycomb, multicore

So, im wondering where I can find some tutorials/examples on how to specify certain task for a second core, or if this is even possible. Im building an app for the Honeycomb tablets, and if the second core is available I want to do some heavy string parsing everytime someone types in a edittext. I tried google, but I couldnt find anything except for news on multi core androids...

Comment: Why do you care whether it's a second code or just one core that's really, really fast? You're thinking about the problem completely wrong.

Comment: Its going to be parsing alot of information, checking each word against arrays of other words. So, I dont want the UI to go unresponsive because its parsing a large file. I had a problem similar to this in a program I made in Visual Studio. I had to parse 43k lines of a text file and insert them into a database and the UI froze. Put in another thread to handle the parsing and it worked just fine. I want to make sure that the UI stays responsive and doesnt become sluggish.

Comment: So then your question is, "How can I do work in a lower-priority thread to keep my UI responsive?" [Thread priority](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#setPriority%28int%29)

Comment: No. In C# you can program for independant cores. If you know the system you are working on has multiple cores, you can specify which core you want your code to run on. Im trying to figure out if that is at all possible. If not, then the debate is done. If already seen what this script does when in a different thread, and its slow and unresponsive at times (the process itself, not the UI). If it isnt possible, then I will have to figure something else out. But, optimally, I want it to run on the second core.

Comment: If you've found the thread slow and unresponsive even on dual-core machines, then you have your answer. It's too slow. Forcing it to a particular core won't make it any faster -- unless it's horribly broken, the scheduler would already run it on the best core. If it's too slow when free to run on any core, taking away that freedom won't make it faster.

Comment: There is no way to specify which core your code runs on.  You'd need to use `sched_setaffinity()`, which requires `CAP_SYS_NICE`, which apps don't have.  As others have noted, the Linux scheduler will take care of this for you -- if you have two busy threads, they will run on separate cores.  If you have two threads that take turns being busy, they'll run on the same core.  The motivation is to allow cores to be turned off to improve battery life... no device would be up for long with 4 cores running at full speed.

Answer (score 3):

i dont think there is a way to specify that in the code. Thread scheduler will take care of using the multicore on its own.

Answer (score 0):

If you UI become unresponsive, it typically just means that you're doing work in UI thread that you shouldn't be doing there. So practically do the work in separate thread (or even create many of them to do the work). Good threading keep UI fluid no matter how many cores you have.

In Android you can use AsyncTask, Java's Threads or Services to do your work.